# Test if remote TCP port is open from a shell script

Tags: shell, tcp, port, solaris, telnet

I'm looking for a quick and simple method for properly testing if a given TCP port is open on a remote server, from inside a Shell script.

I've managed to do it with the telnet command, and it works fine when the port is opened, but it doesn't seem to timeout when it's not and just hangs there...

Here's a sample:

```
l_TELNET=`echo "quit" | telnet $SERVER $PORT | grep "Escape character is"`
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Connection to $SERVER on port $PORT failed"
  exit 1
else
  echo "Connection to $SERVER on port $PORT succeeded"
  exit 0
fi
```

I either need a better way, or a way to force telnet to timeout if it doesn't connect in under 8 seconds for example, and return something I can catch in Shell (return code, or string in stdout).

I know of the Perl method, which uses the IO::Socket::INET module and wrote a successful script that tests a port, but would rather like to avoid using Perl if possible.

Note: This is what my server is running (where I need to run this from)

SunOS 5.10 Generic_139556-08 i86pc i386 i86pc

Comment: What about [Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) or [Nmap](http://www.nmap.org/)?

Comment: The answer lied with Expect. We wrote a simple script that sends a telnet on the port we needed, with a timeout of 8 seconds. There's plenty of examples to pick from too. We based ours off this post: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/146568-expect-telnet-testing-tacacs-cisco.html

Comment: check_tcp from https://github.com/monitoring-plugins/monitoring-plugins
can do this, including entering strings and checking for an expected answer.

Answer (score 543):

As pointed by B. Rhodes, `nc` ([`netcat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat)) will do the job. A more compact way to use it:

```
nc -z <host> <port>
```

That way `nc` will only check if the port is open, exiting with 0 on success, 1 on failure.

For a quick interactive check (with a 5 seconds timeout):

```
nc -z -v -w5 <host> <port>
```

Comment: centos7 default use nmap netcat and has not -z option.

Comment: This doesn't work in RHEL/Centos. For those distros you need to:
nc -vn <host> <port>

Comment: FWIW, I have completely overhauled [my answer with an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14701003/832230), separately applicable to both RHEL 6 and RHEL 7.

Comment: @JustinDennahower In `nc -vn <host> <port>`, `-n` does not resolve a domain name. I think people should also drop the `n` option.

Comment: nc: invalid option -- 'z'

Comment: @YevgenyTaradayko maybe you are using nmap netcat. See jolestar comment above.

Comment: on Mac at least, you may need to add `-G#` to set a connection timeout separate from/in addition to the `-w#` timeout, which basically functions as a read timeout.

Comment: @jolestar You can manually upgrade Ncat on Centos 7 to get the `-z` option. You may want to consider: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393762/how-to-manually-update-nmaps-netcat-on-centos-7

Comment: Is <host> the server ip address?  If I'm running nc -z -v -w5 <host> <port> on the server that I'm opening ports on, do I need to provide host in nc command?

Comment: @Michele, yes, it's the host you want to test. It may well be localhost.

Comment: On my debian8 nc -vz works while nc -z returns nothing.

Comment: @NormanBai, that's expected, and described in the answer. Without `-v` you should manually check the _exit code_ returned (e.g. with `echo $?`). The non verbose form is useful for scripting.

Comment: works great in Ubuntu

Answer (score 205):

It's easy enough to do with the `-z` and `-w TIMEOUT` options to `nc`, but not all systems have `nc` installed. If you have a recent enough version of bash, this will work:

```
# Connection successful:
$ timeout 1 bash -c 'cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/google.com/80'
$ echo $?
0

# Connection failure prior to the timeout
$ timeout 1 bash -c 'cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/sfsfdfdff.com/80'
bash: sfsfdfdff.com: Name or service not known
bash: /dev/tcp/sfsfdfdff.com/80: Invalid argument
$ echo $?
1

# Connection not established by the timeout
$ timeout 1 bash -c 'cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/google.com/81'
$ echo $?
124
```

What's happening here is that `timeout` will run the subcommand and kill it if it doesn't exit within the specified timeout (1 second in the above example). In this case `bash` is the subcommand and uses its special [/dev/tcp handling](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/devref1.html#DEVTCP) to try and open a connection to the server and port specified. If `bash` can open the connection within the timeout, `cat` will just close it immediately (since it's reading from `/dev/null`) and exit with a status code of `0` which will propagate through `bash` and then `timeout`. If `bash` gets a connection failure prior to the specified timeout, then `bash` will exit with an exit code of 1 which `timeout` will also return. And if bash isn't able to establish a connection and the specified timeout expires, then `timeout` will kill `bash` and exit with a status of 124.

Use a different syntax for **Git Bash**:

```
$ timeout 1 bash -c '< /dev/tcp/google.com/80'
$ echo $?
0
```

Otherwise, **Git Bash** will return an error where none is expected:

```
$ timeout 1 bash -c 'cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/google.com/80'
$ echo $?
124
```

Comment: Is `/dev/tcp` available on systems other than Linux? What about Macs in particular?

Comment: The /dev/tcp thing is a feature of bash, so yes. However it looks like macs don't have timeout...

Comment: @onlynone - Looks like `timeout` also doesn't exist in FreeBSD, and on my old Ubuntu box it's an installable package, but isn't there by default. Would be great if there was a way to do this in bash alone, without third party tools like timeout or netcat.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that `timeout` appears to be part of GNU coreutils, and can be installed on macs with homebrew: `brew install coreutils`. It'll then be available as `gtimeout`.

Comment: Hey, this is great.  What version of `bash` was this introduced in, does anyone know?  (How could I find out?)

Comment: @A-B-B, thanks for the info, but I was talking about the special `/dev/tcp` handling, and wondering when that was introduced to `bash`.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard A bash [change log](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) suggests `bash-2.04-devel`, although support for host names may have been added in `bash-2.05-alpha1`.

Comment: If `/dev/{tcp,udp}` does not show up on your Linux distribution, you can go directly to the underlying device in `/proc/net/{tcp,udp}`.

Answer (score 137):

### TOC:

- Using bash and `timeout`

  - Command
  - Examples
- Using `nc`

  - Command
  - RHEL 6 (nc-1.84)

    - Installation
    - Examples
  - RHEL 7 (nmap-ncat-6.40)

    - Installation
    - Examples
- Remarks

## Using bash and `timeout`:

Note that `timeout` should be present with RHEL 6+, or is alternatively found in GNU coreutils 8.22. On MacOS, install it using `brew install coreutils` and use it as `gtimeout`.

### Command:

```
$ timeout $TIMEOUT_SECONDS bash -c "</dev/tcp/${HOST}/${PORT}"; echo $?
```

If parametrizing the host and port, be sure to specify them as `${HOST}` and `${PORT}` as is above. Do not specify them merely as `$HOST` and `$PORT`, i.e. without the braces; it won't work in this case.

### Example:

#### Success:

```
$ timeout 2 bash -c "</dev/tcp/canyouseeme.org/80"; echo $?
0
```

#### Failure:

```
$ timeout 2 bash -c "</dev/tcp/canyouseeme.org/81"; echo $?
124
```

If you must preserve the exit status of `bash`,

```
$ timeout --preserve-status 2 bash -c "</dev/tcp/canyouseeme.org/81"; echo $?
143
```

## Using `nc`:

Note that a backward incompatible version of `nc` gets installed on RHEL 7.

### Command:

Note that the command below is unique in that it is identical for both RHEL 6 and 7. It's just the installation and output that are different.

```
$ nc -w $TIMEOUT_SECONDS -v $HOST $PORT </dev/null; echo $?
```

### RHEL 6 (nc-1.84):

#### Installation:

```
$ sudo yum install nc
```

#### Examples:

Success:

```
$ nc -w 2 -v canyouseeme.org 80 </dev/null; echo $?
Connection to canyouseeme.org 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
0
```

Failure:

```
$ nc -w 2 -v canyouseeme.org 81 </dev/null; echo $?
nc: connect to canyouseeme.org port 81 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
1
```

If the hostname maps to multiple IPs, the above failing command will cycle through many or all of them. For example:

```
$ nc -w 2 -v microsoft.com 81 </dev/null; echo $?
nc: connect to microsoft.com port 81 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
nc: connect to microsoft.com port 81 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
nc: connect to microsoft.com port 81 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
nc: connect to microsoft.com port 81 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
nc: connect to microsoft.com port 81 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
1
```

### RHEL 7 (nmap-ncat-6.40):

#### Installation:

```
$ sudo yum install nmap-ncat
```

#### Examples:

Success:

```
$ nc -w 2 -v canyouseeme.org 80 </dev/null; echo $?
Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 52.202.215.126:80.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.22 seconds.
0
```

Failure:

```
$ nc -w 2 -v canyouseeme.org 81 </dev/null; echo $?
Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection timed out.
1
```

If the hostname maps to multiple IPs, the above failing command will cycle through many or all of them. For example:

```
$ nc -w 2 -v microsoft.com 81 </dev/null; echo $?
Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection to 104.43.195.251 failed: Connection timed out.
Ncat: Trying next address...
Ncat: Connection to 23.100.122.175 failed: Connection timed out.
Ncat: Trying next address...
Ncat: Connection to 23.96.52.53 failed: Connection timed out.
Ncat: Trying next address...
Ncat: Connection to 191.239.213.197 failed: Connection timed out.
Ncat: Trying next address...
Ncat: Connection timed out.
1
```

## Remarks:

The `-v` (`--verbose`) argument and the `echo $?` command are of course for illustration only.

Comment: `timeout 2 bash -c "</dev/tcp/canyouseeme.org/81"; echo $?`is great point!

Comment: add `2>&1` to not echo status  `result_test=$(nc -w 2 $ip_addreess 80 </dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?) `

Answer (score 64):

With `netcat` you can check whether a port is open like this:

```
nc my.example.com 80 < /dev/null
```

The return value of `nc` will be success if the TCP port was opened, and failure (typically the return code 1) if it could not make the TCP connection.

Some versions of `nc` will hang when you try this, because they do not close the sending half of their socket even after receiving the end-of-file from `/dev/null`. On my own Ubuntu laptop (18.04), the `netcat-openbsd` version of netcat that I have installed offers a workaround: the `-N` option is necessary to get an immediate result:

```
nc -N my.example.com 80 < /dev/null
```

Comment: Works great for flavours of  `nc` that don't support the `-w` flag.

Comment: thanks - also works for versions of nc without `-z` support - works on RHEL/CentOS 7, for example

Comment: Although this approach is good, `-w` is necessary, failing which the command when used in a script can hang for over ten seconds. I have written an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14701003/832230) which includes `-w`.

Comment: +1 this is great because nc comes standard with alpine linux and ubuntu both. probably others. no need to install extra when you're remoted in and can't. thanks for this! I might add, `nc host port -w 2 && echo it works`

Comment: I prefer `nc -vz localhost 3306`. It gives a more verbose output. Tried it on mac only.

Comment: This does not work with the `netcat-openbsd` nor the `netcat-traditional` implementation on Debian. The command will just block and not return.

Comment: @josch Maybe the host is unreachable so no answer is coming back either way about whether the port is open? You might want to use `ping` to do a basic connectivity check first if you're dealing with hosts that might not be up or responding.

Comment: @BrandonRhodes you can reproduce my observation using `python3 -m http.server 8000` and then `nc 127.0.0.1 8000 < /dev/null`. The latter command stalls. Clearly, 127.0.0.1 *is* reachable.

Comment: @josch Thanks for a test case! On my Ubuntu laptop, I did indeed require an additional option `-N` to get it not to hang; I've updated the answer.

Comment: @BrandonRhodes you might want to mention that the `-N` option is not available in all versions of netcat either. You are probably using the `netcat-openbsd` package but the `netcat-traditional` package doesn't have this option.

Comment: @josch I checked, and it's indeed the openbsd package! I updated the answer to mention that.

Answer (score 39):

In Bash using [pseudo-device files](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/devref1.html) for TCP/UDP connections is straight forward. Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
SERVER=example.com
PORT=80
</dev/tcp/$SERVER/$PORT
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Connection to $SERVER on port $PORT failed"
  exit 1
else
  echo "Connection to $SERVER on port $PORT succeeded"
  exit 0
fi
```

Testing:

```
$ ./test.sh 
Connection to example.com on port 80 succeeded
```

---

Here is one-liner (Bash syntax):

```
</dev/tcp/localhost/11211 && echo Port open. || echo Port closed.
```

---

Note that some servers can be firewall protected from SYN flood attacks, so you may experience a TCP connection timeout (~75secs). To workaround the timeout issue, try:

```
timeout 1 bash -c "</dev/tcp/stackoverflow.com/81" && echo Port open. || echo Port closed.
```

See: [How to decrease TCP connect() system call timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24317341/55075)

Comment: @A-B-B This is related to firewall configuration of the server which doesn't give any response to prevent any SYN flood attacks. Running `telnet canyouseeme.org 81` also hangs. This is controlled by your timeout limits which probably are hardcoded in bash. See: [decrease TCP connect() system call timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24317341/55075).

Comment: For parametrization, it now seems to be necessary to specify `$SERVER` and `$PORT` with braces, at least as `${SERVER}` and `${PORT}`.

Answer (score 15):

I needed a more flexible solution for working on multiple git repositories so I wrote the following sh code based on [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9463554/886607) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35338529/886607). You can use your server address instead of gitlab.com and your port in replace of 22.

```
SERVER=gitlab.com
PORT=22
nc -z -v -w5 $SERVER $PORT
result1=$?

#Do whatever you want

if [  "$result1" != 0 ]; then
  echo  'port 22 is closed'
else
  echo 'port 22 is open'
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! It makes my life easy for /etc/rc.local

Comment: For one liner use `if [[ $( nc -z -v -w5 $SERVER 22 >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $?) -eq 0 ]]; then`

Answer (score 14):

## check ports using bash

### Example

```
$ ./test_port_bash.sh 192.168.7.7 22
```

the port 22 is open

### Code

```
HOST=$1
PORT=$2
exec 3> /dev/tcp/${HOST}/${PORT}
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then echo "the port $2 is open";else echo "the port $2 is closed";fi
```

Answer (score 12):

If you're using **ksh** or **bash** they both support IO redirection to/from a socket using the **/dev/tcp/IP/PORT** construct. In this **Korn shell** example I am redirecting no-op's (**:**) std-in from a socket:

```
W$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer &
[1]     16833
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
W$ : </dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8000
```

The shell prints an error if the socket is not open:

```
W$ : </dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8001
ksh: /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8001: cannot open [Connection refused]
```

You can therefore use this as the **test** in an **if** condition:

```
SERVER=127.0.0.1 PORT=8000
if (: < /dev/tcp/$SERVER/$PORT) 2>/dev/null
then
    print succeeded
else
    print failed
fi
```

The no-op is in a subshell so I can throw std-err away if the std-in redirection fails.

I often use **/dev/tcp** for checking the availability of a resource over HTTP:

```
W$ print arghhh > grr.html
W$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer &
[1]     16863
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
W$ (print -u9 'GET /grr.html HTTP/1.0\n';cat <&9) 9<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8000
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/2.6.1
Date: Thu, 14 Feb 2013 12:56:29 GMT
Content-type: text/html
Content-Length: 7
Last-Modified: Thu, 14 Feb 2013 12:55:44 GMT

arghhh
W$
```

This one-liner opens **file descriptor 9** for reading from and writing to the socket, prints the **HTTP GET** to the socket and uses **`cat`** to read from the socket.

Comment: @A-B-B I think you mean it hangs for a long time if the port is not responding, as for instance when filtered, or nothing is on the IP.  A closed port does not cause a delay if the port actively refuses the connection.  For many purposes this is quite acceptable.

Comment: This technique was already posted before this answer in a [prior answer by kenorb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35338529/832230). Anyway, the bigger point is that it however hangs for a long time if the port is not responding. For example, try `</dev/tcp/canyouseeme.org/80` and then `</dev/tcp/canyouseeme.org/81`.

Answer (score 9):

While an old question, I've just dealt with a variant of it, but none of the solutions here were applicable, so I found another, and am adding it for posterity.  Yes, I know the OP said they were aware of this option and it didn't suit them, but for anyone following afterwards it might prove useful.

In my case, I want to test for the availability of a local `apt-cacher-ng` service from a `docker` build.  That means absolutely nothing can be installed prior to the test.  No `nc`, `nmap`, `expect`, `telnet` or `python`.  `perl` however is present, along with the core libraries, so I used this:

```
perl -MIO::Socket::INET -e 'exit(! defined( IO::Socket::INET->new("172.17.42.1:3142")))'
```

Answer (score 7):

In some cases where tools like curl, telnet, nc o nmap are unavailable you still have a chance with wget

```
if [[ $(wget -q -t 1 --spider --dns-timeout 3 --connect-timeout 10  host:port; echo $?) -eq 0 ]]; then echo "OK"; else echo "FAIL"; fi
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `nc` but don't have a version that support `-z`, try using `--send-only`:

```
nc --send-only <IP> <PORT> </dev/null
```

and with timeout:

```
nc -w 1 --send-only <IP> <PORT> </dev/null
```

and without DNS lookup if it's an IP:

```
nc -n -w 1 --send-only <IP> <PORT> </dev/null
```

It returns the codes as the `-z` based on if it can connect or not.

Answer (score 3):

Building on the most highly voted answer, here is a function to wait for two ports to be open, with a timeout as well. Note the two ports that mus be open, 8890 and 1111, as well as the max_attempts (1 per second).

```
function wait_for_server_to_boot()
{
    echo "Waiting for server to boot up..."
    attempts=0
    max_attempts=30
    while ( nc 127.0.0.1 8890 < /dev/null || nc 127.0.0.1 1111 < /dev/null )  && [[ $attempts < $max_attempts ]] ; do
        attempts=$((attempts+1))
        sleep 1;
        echo "waiting... (${attempts}/${max_attempts})"
    done
}
```

Comment: No success/fail return code?

Answer (score 1):

I needed short script which was run in cron and hasn't output. I solve my trouble using nmap

```
open=`nmap -p $PORT $SERVER | grep "$PORT" | grep open`
if [ -z "$open" ]; then
  echo "Connection to $SERVER on port $PORT failed"
  exit 1
else
  echo "Connection to $SERVER on port $PORT succeeded"
  exit 0
fi
```

To run it You should install nmap because it is not default installed package.

Comment: `nmap`'s grepable output might also be useful `-oG -` to send it to stdout. (the grep would need a bit of modification)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that it's too late for an answer, and this might not be a good one, but here you go...

What about putting it inside of a while loop with a timer on it of some sort.  I'm more of a Perl guy than Solaris, but depending on the shell you're using, you should be able to do something like:

```
TIME = 'date +%s' + 15
while TIME != `date +%s'
do whatever
```

And then just add a flag in the while loop, so that if it times out before completing, you can cite the timeout as reason for failure.

I suspect that the telnet has a timeout switch as well, but just off the top of my head, I think the above will work.

Answer (score 0):

This uses telnet behind the scenes, and seems to work fine on mac/linux. It doesn't use netcat because of the differences between the versions on linux/mac, and this works with a default mac install.

#### Example:

```
$ is_port_open.sh 80 google.com
OPEN

$ is_port_open.sh 8080 google.com
CLOSED
```

#### is_port_open.sh

```
PORT=$1
HOST=$2
TIMEOUT_IN_SEC=${3:-1}
VALUE_IF_OPEN=${4:-"OPEN"}
VALUE_IF_CLOSED=${5:-"CLOSED"}

function eztern()
{
  if [ "$1" == "$2" ]
  then
    echo $3
  else
    echo $4
  fi
}

# cross platform timeout util to support mac mostly
# https://gist.github.com/jaytaylor/6527607
function eztimeout() { perl -e 'alarm shift; exec @ARGV' "$@"; }

function testPort()
{
  OPTS=""

  # find out if port is open using telnet
  # by saving telnet output to temporary file
  # and looking for "Escape character" response
  # from telnet
  FILENAME="/tmp/__port_check_$(uuidgen)"
  RESULT=$(eztimeout $TIMEOUT_IN_SEC telnet $HOST $PORT &> $FILENAME; cat $FILENAME | tail -n1)
  rm -f $FILENAME;
  SUCCESS=$(eztern "$RESULT" "Escape character is '^]'." "$VALUE_IF_OPEN" "$VALUE_IF_CLOSED")

  echo "$SUCCESS"
}

testPort
```

Answer (score 0):

My machine does not support `nc` or `/dev/tcp/$hostname/$port` but `timeout`, so I came back to `telnet` as follows:

```
if echo "quit" | timeout 2 telnet $SERVER $PORT 2>&1 | grep -q 'Connected to'; then
    echo "Connection to $SERVER on port $PORT succeeded"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Connection to $SERVER on port $PORT failed"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#------------------------------------+
# checkout target server port status |
# with DOH service.                  |
#------------------------------------+
#


A_LIST=$(curl -Ssl --http2 -H "accept: application/dns-json" "https://1.1.1.1/dns-query?name=example.com&type=A" |jq -r '.Answer[]|.data'|tr '\n\t' '|'|sed 's/|*\r*$//')

echo $A_LIST

for SERVER in $(echo $A_LIST | sed "s/|/ /g");do
    echo "$SERVER"
    timeout 3 bash -c "</dev/tcp/$SERVER/80" && echo -e open|| echo -e failed
done
```

Answer (score -1):

## nmap-ncat to test for local port that is not already in use

---

```
availabletobindon() {
  port="$1"
  nc -w 2 -i 1 localhost "$port" 2>&1 | grep -v -q 'Idle timeout expired'
  return "$?"
}
```

Comment: It doesn't tell me that my port 80 is open.