# semantics of `exec $FILE_DESCRIPTOR<>`?

Tags: bash

I recently saw [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609247/915044)

> Bash natively supports tcp connections as file descriptors. To use:
>
> ```
> exec 6<>/dev/tcp/ip.addr.of.server/445
> echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.0\n" >&6
> cat <&6
> ```
>
> I'm using 6 as the file descriptor because 0, 1, 2 are stdin, stdout, and stderr. 5 is sometimes used by Bash for child processes, so 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, and 9 should be safe.

What *I* don't understand and have never seen before is the `exec 6<>` in the first line. What does that mean (given that `6` can presumably be any generic file descriptor, as discussed in the quote)? Particularly I don't recall ever seeing `<>` in a bash script before.

Apologies if this is a FAQ, but my usual search engines either don't record or refuse to search for `<>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `bash` extension that allows opening a single descriptor in read-write mode. This is typically used with sockets, to allow bidirectional communication (e.g. reading a request and sending a reply).

From the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

> **Opening File Descriptors for Reading and Writing**
>
> The redirection operator
>      **[n]<>word**
> causes the file whose name is the expansion of *word* to be opened for both reading and writing on file descriptor *n*, or on file descriptor 0 if n is not specified. If the file does not exist, it is created.

Comment: Thanks! for extra credit: in which bash version was this introduced? Alternatively, for which bash versions should I expect a script using this syntax to fail?

Answer (score 1):

Using "bash redirect" as my search term I found [that syntax](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) is explained as a way to create a file descriptor with the given name, `6` in this case. The file that will be open follows the `<>` syntax.

Thus it looks like bash is opening a file descriptor for I/O and sending an HTTP GET and dumping the output to `stdout`.