# Need help understanding the command

Tags: bash

I found this command at [Quick way to find if a port is open on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609130/quick-way-to-find-if-a-port-is-open-on-linux#_=_).

```
exec 6<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/445 || echo "No one is listening!"
```

I am a newbie to shell scripting. Could anyone please explain me in detail the syntax of this command?
Especially `exec 6<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/445`. Also is exec going to return a bool value or something (since `||` is being used?)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It literally explains it in the post ?

Comment: i didnot understand the use of <>. Also can we use exec 6<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/445 in an if statement somehow?

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html and yes the `||` is effectively an `else` as it short circuits if the first command is successful.

Comment: how to include it in a script

Comment: How to include what ?

Comment: You mean we can write something like  if [exec 6<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/445] ?

Comment: rather: `if exec 6<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/445; then echo port open; fi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<>
```

does I/O redirection for both reading and writing.
See [I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

The `6` means we assign it to file descriptor six. [What are file descriptors?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7082184/1902598)

`||` is in bash executed when the lefthand-side command failed. In other words, this in an `else`