# Strongloop Loopback explorer not showing when on remote server

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I've built an strongloop loopback API server locally and everything worked fine but when I've uploaded it to my remote server the SLC RUN command runs fine (I can see it in terminal it actually created my test models in MySQL db on the same server) but yet I can't access the example.com/explorer page to see the APIs...do I need to configure something differently to have it work when it's on a remote server?

I changed the port from 3000 to 3001. Here is my config.json file in the server file.

```
{
"restApiRoot": "/api",
"host": "www.example.com",
"port": 3001,
"remoting": {
"context": {
  "enableHttpContext": false
},
"rest": {
  "normalizeHttpPath": false,
  "xml": false
},
"json": {
  "strict": false,
  "limit": "100kb"
},
"urlencoded": {
  "extended": true,
  "limit": "100kb"
},
"cors": {
  "origin": true,
  "credentials": true
},
"errorHandler": {
  "disableStackTrace": false
}
 }
}
```

and the explorer file in the boot directory (yes I did run the npm install loopback-explorer)...

```
module.exports = function mountLoopBackExplorer(server) {
var explorer;
try {
explorer = require('loopback-explorer');
 } catch(err) {
// Print the message only when the app was started via `server.listen()`.
// Do not print any message when the project is used as a component.
server.once('started', function(baseUrl) {
  console.log(
    'Run `npm install loopback-explorer` to enable the LoopBack explorer'
  );
});
 return;
}

var restApiRoot = server.get('restApiRoot');

var explorerApp = explorer(server, { basePath: restApiRoot });
server.use('/explorer', explorerApp);
server.once('started', function() {
var baseUrl = server.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
// express 4.x (loopback 2.x) uses `mountpath`
// express 3.x (loopback 1.x) uses `route`
var explorerPath = explorerApp.mountpath || explorerApp.route;
console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
});
};
```

Comment: you mean example.com:3001/explorer right? (not example.com/explorer) or is there some proxy server passing through to your node instance?

Comment: yes sorry I mean example.com:3001/explorer...any ideas why I'm having this issue?

Comment: is that port open on the machine you are connecting to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609130/quick-way-to-find-if-a-port-is-open-on-linux)? is it an EC2 instance?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Stack trace? What is different on your remote server? Is the port open?

Comment: No I've built it on a dedicated server and doing the command below on my mac returns 1: nc ip port < www.example.com:3001; echo $?

Comment: Thanks guys the port was the issue....damn...I wish I would've thought of that. So obvious! :)

Comment: Can you upload the code somewhere? Not sure what is different on your remote server. If it works locally, just do the same on the remote server.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I solved the problem. It wasn't the code but the fact that my remote server didn't have the right port opened. I appreciate your help!

Comment: NP, glad you got it working. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The port was the issue, see the comments in the question. Closed.