# Use a node app from another device locally

Tags: node.js, networking, local

I have a server (`10.0.0.12`) and my laptop (`10.0.0.2`) on a local network.

When I run `curl http://10.0.0.2:3000` on the server, it works fine. When I run `curl http://10.0.0.12:3000` on my laptop, it doesn't work saying site is unavailable.

I am able to ping and ssh into the server from my laptop.

Here is my code to finish the connection:

```
app.set('port', (3000));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Node app running on localhost:" + app.get('port'));
}
```

I've tried passing in an ip address to the `listen()` function, but made no difference. I tried passing in `10.0.0.12` (the ip address of the server), `127.0.0.1`, and `0.0.0.0` all with the same result.

How can I host my node app on a local network and have everyone who is on the local network be able to access it through the browser?

EDIT: I'm running on CentOS 7.

EDIT2: When I run `netstat -lnt`, it says this:

`tcp      0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just omit the IP address? It should then be available on the IP address of the machine it is running on and the specified port.

Comment: Yeah, I tried omitting it, but still the same. In the API, when you omit the if, it defaults to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Any local router or firewall.

Comment: I'm pretty sure nothing is blocking it. The only thing between my server and laptop is the router and I'm pretty sure it's not blocking. I'll check my servers firewall.

Comment: Nope. My router isn't blocking anything and neither is my server.

Comment: what's your network mask ? / server OS ?  and check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609130/quick-way-to-find-if-a-port-is-open-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by HA. remove the IP.

As you can see from the documentation:
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback
If the hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections directed to any IPv4 address (INADDR_ANY).

P.S. Which is the OS on the server?

Comment: Which firewall are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try :

```
app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function(){
    console.log("Node app running on 0.0.0.0:3000");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible issue could be you aren't using the http module?

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('App running on port 3000');
});
```

A good practice would be set the port like

```
app.set('port', (3000));

var http = require('http').Server(app);

http.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('App running on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Node run fine. It just when I try to access the app from a different source on the same network, it can gain access.