# Created a project in laravel but I can't access a welcome page

Tags: php, laravel

I installed Laravel (in W10/Wamp3.3/PHP5.6) using Composer and created a new project with the following command:

```
laravel new my_project
```

Project doesn't have a welcome page, opens file-list directly. So I decided to try my chance on creating a new controller and create a route.

```
php artisan make:controller Hello
```

And my route in routes/web

```
Route::get('/hello', 'HelloController@index');
```

I also cleared the route cache:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Created the controller with no methods. myproject/hello shows nothing.

What am I missing? File permissions or wamp based problem?

There's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576341/cannot-get-laravel-welcome-page-to-show) related with this but it's more like a server problem.

Comment: Are you pointing your webserver to your laravel project's `/public` directory?

Comment: first , you can run `php artisan make:controller HelloController` instead of  `php artisan make:controller Hello`

Comment: Are you getting Error or Warning ?

Comment: You should have PHP 7 or greater if not running Homestead

Try running 'php artisan serve' in CMD and report back.

Comment: Do you have a `.env` file in your project?

Comment: Hello Polaris, thanks for artisan serve, application started. I installed latest version of wamp today. May be it has some caching problem. I flushed the cache but nothing worked.

Comment: If you say that your controller has no methods, what might return `view` fro your welcome than? Your route doesn't have `Closure`.

Comment: When you say "opens file-list directly", what directory does it open? The public dir, or the root dir?

Answer (score 1):

Few causes for this that I've run into. Most likely one is going to be the server pointing to the incorrect directory. What I would do to test is run `php artisan serve` from the root of the project. This will open up a server pointing to public directory. If this functions correctly then you have confirmation.