# Bash: Close MySQL connection when server fails

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I have a simple script to connect to a extern MySQL server.

```
#!/bin/bash
server=1.2.3.1
port=3306
user=root
pass=root
db=radius

output=$(mysql -N -h $server -u $user -p$pass $db -e  "select * from table)
echo "$output"
```

The problem is when the mysql service fails on server 1.2.3.1, because the script  gets stucked waiting for answer a long time!

How can I wait only for 1 second and if server doesn't respond, the script kills the process?
Or how can I check if the service is up on the remote server before?

Regards.

Comment: This might help: [Quick way to find if a port is open on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9609130/3776858)

Comment: `--connect_timeout=1`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this out but I suppose you could set a timer and then test whether your result has a value.

```
#!/bin/bash
server=1.2.3.1
port=3306
user=root
pass=root
db=radius

output=$(mysql -N -h $server -u $user -p$pass $db -e  "select * from table)
sleep 1
if ! [[ $output ]]
   mysql exit
fi
echo "$output"
```