# How to display nc return value in Linux shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, netcat

I am using `nc` command in my Linux box like below to check if a port is listening;

This displays success message:

```
nc -z 192.168.0.2 9000
```

This displays 0:

```
echo $?
```

I have combined it in a shell script .sh file like below;

```
#!/bin/sh
nc -z 192.168.0.2 9000
echo $?
```

This displays `1` instead of expected `0`. Again, if I modify my script like below, it works;

```
#!/bin/sh
echo nc -z 192.168.0.2 9000
echo $?
```

But here the problem is, it displays success message on one like, then displays 0 in next line. I don't want success message, and I am expecting 0. What is wrong here and how can I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922943/test-from-shell-script-if-remote-tcp-port-is-open

Answer (score 3):

This small script should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVER=$1
PORT=$2
nc -z -v -G5 $SERVER $PORT &> /dev/null
result1=$?

#Do whatever you want

if [  "$result1" != 0 ]; then
  echo  port $PORT is closed on $SERVER
else
  echo port $PORT is open on $SERVER
fi
```

Usage:

```
./myscript.sh servername portnumber
```

For example:

```
./myscript www.google.com 80
www.google.com 80
port 80 is open on www.google.com
```

Depending on the version of nc you're using, you may need to adjust the -G to -w, so experiment and find which works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your script works as expected for me.
(Using nc 0.7.1 and sh 4.4.12)

Both, on command line as well as a script using `#!/bin/sh`

Just your last version - `echo nc -z 192.168.0.2 9000` - does not execute nc at all but just echoes it out. Try replacing `nc` with anything, e.g. `ncc-1701` and you'll see what i mean.