# How to use the exit code of netcat command in a if condition?

Tags: bash, exit-code, netcat

I have this function in bash that uses netcat to check that a port is open on an address. As an example, I am testing with localhost 3000.

**ERROR**

I am having trouble getting the error code from running `nc`. I keep seeing the messge:

> nc_output: integer expression expected

from the if-condition. (See CODE below)

**CODE**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o nounset

scan() {
  local host=$1
  local port=$2
  local nc_output

  nc_output=$(nc ${host} ${port} -w 5)
  eval ${nc_output}
  if [ nc_output -ne 0 ]; then
     "PORT ${port} CLOSED on ${host}"
  else
    echo "PORT ${port} OPEN on ${host}"
  fi
}

scan 127.0.0.1 3000
```

Comment: `if [ "$nc_output" -ne 0 ]; then` (note the dollar sign before the variable), what you have compares a literal string `nc_output` with `0`

Comment: What is `eval ${nc_output}` supposed to do?

Comment: "*nc output is not an exit code*" is correct (output and exit codes are different things), but what does that have to do with your question?

Comment: @melpomene I am trying to run the nc command by using `eval ${nc_output}` which should run the command.

Comment: That makes no sense. `$(nc ${host} ${port} -w 5)` already runs `nc`.

Comment: @melpomene I got it working with `nc -z ${host} ${port}` followed by `nc_output=$?` on the next line.

Comment: @melpomene: I think OP most likely wrongly used a command substitution syntax instead of just plain variable assignment. Maybe the intention was to assign the `nc` command in a variable and `eval` it (which is a bad approach also)

Comment: That means `nc_output` is misnamed. `$?` is the exit code, not the output.

Comment: @melpomene Good call. I renamed it to `nc_exit_code`.

Comment: If all you're doing is testing the exit status, you could just write `if nc ${host} ${port} -w 5; then echo "open"; fi`.

Comment: Closely a duplicate of [How to display nc return value in Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42377276/5291015), but this needed an explanation to what was wrong with OP's attempt

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the problem comes down to usage of how you are storing the `nc` command in a variable to `eval` it later. When you did

```
nc_output=$(nc ${host} ${port} -w 5)
#          ^^                      ^
```

The marked syntax `$(..)` is for command substitution in `bash`, which runs the command inside and stores the output  of the command in the variable used. So the above line runs the `nc` command and stores the output returned in the variable `nc_output`. Remember this only stores the standard output of the command and *not* the return code of the `nc` command which should been fetched from the variable `$?`

I'm guessing your intention was to store the command in a variable and then `eval` it once and get the exit code, but you are doing it wrong by `eval`-ing the output returned from the `nc` command which is roundabout and unnecessary.

The ideal way should have been just

```
nc "${host}" "${port}" -w 5
nc_exit_code=$?
```

and use this variable in the condition

```
if [ "$nc_exit_code" -ne 0 ]; then
```

Note that the `$` prefix before the variable name. You need to use the `$var` syntax to access the value of the identifier `var` in shell syntax. You weren't using the symbol in your original post. Not doing so will compare a literal string `nc_output` with `0` which does not make sense as the native types of two are different from one another.

Also storing this exit code explicitly in a variable is redundant, the `if` conditionals work directly on the exit code of the command returned, so just

```
if ! nc "${host}" "${port}" -w 5; then
    echo "PORT ${port} CLOSED on ${host}"
else
    echo "PORT ${port} OPEN on ${host}"
fi
```

should be sufficient for your logic.