# Can't access node_exporter from public ip address on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I am setting up [prometheus/node_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) on AWS EC2. With the following configuration

```
[Unit]
Description=Node Exporter
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=node_exporter
Group=node_exporter
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node_exporter

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I can access metrics by using curl with localhost. Something like the following

```
curl localhost:9100/metrics
```

I can access the metric via private IP address as well. For example

```
curl private_ip_address:9100/metrics
```

But, when I try to access it via public IP address. It's not working, got curl timeout.

```
curl public_ip_address:9100/metrics
```

I try accessing from the `ipv4:9100` from the server itself and from my local machine. Both got the same issue.

How can I enable to make it accessible from the ipv4 address?

Comment: If its blocked from the inside, maybe you have some firewall (e.g. `ufw`) blocking the port on the instance?

Comment: @Marcin I already added the port 9000 to the firewall as well.

Comment: Can you disable ufw for a moment just to double check it effects?

Comment: @Marcin It's resolved. I need to add a custom TCP inbound rule in my AWS security group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, EC2 instances do not allow accessing the port directly.

You need to create a `Custom TCP` rule for the port `9100` in the **Inbound rules** if it does not exist.

If you have also configured a firewall, you need to allow port `9100` too.

You can test remote ports are reachable or not (REF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9463554/664229):

```
nc -zvw 5 <ip> <port>
```

Comment: how to setup routing on aws account where prometheus is running to collect metrics from a different aws account where node-exporter is installed on the ec2 instance. All aws accounts are within the same AZ