# How to check if a connection can be made to a port in bash

Tags: bash, shell, port

I would like to check if I can connect to a port or not from within a bash script

Based on the answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922943/test-if-remote-tcp-port-is-open-from-a-shell-script) I tried running

```
nc -zvw10 <host> <port>
```

and check if the status code is 0/1

but many times it returns "Connection refused" and exits the script (there doesnt seem to be a return code)

I only want to exit the script if it returns a 0, which means a connection is made.

Comment: The script ending indicates that you are using `set -e`; don't do that, or update your question to explain why you need it and what you have done to cope with the consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boolean operators:

```
#!/bin/bash
nc -zvw10 $1 $2 && exit 1 || echo "continue."
echo "It continues."
```

And on a closed port, it stops:

```
bash bar.sh localhost 2048
nc: connect to localhost port 2048 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
continue.
It continues.
```

So on open port:

```
bash bar.sh localhost 2049
Connection to localhost 2049 port [tcp/nfs] succeeded!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the output and error stream to /dev/null using `nc -zvw10 <host> <port> &>/dev/null`